# Create DB: Initial Size vs Max Size

Tags: sql-server, database-size

In SQL Server, when creating a database we can specify the (initial) SIZE and the MAX_SIZE. I don't understand the difference.

When I create the database, it's empty. So it's size is **zero**.

Therefore, the initial size seems to be more like an estimation, how much of the hard drive should I ask the operating system to reserve for me.

But then, this is just what I think the MAX_SIZE is.

So can anyone tell me what SIZE and MAX_SIZE actually are?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the MSDN link for full details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=sqlpool#size-size, but in brief:

- SIZE - The initial size of the file, how big you want the file to be initially.
- MAXSIZE - The absolute maximum size of the file you want.

These two values also interact with FILEGROWTH.

When you initially create the database, you specify the initial size.  However, if the file fills up, it will use the FILEGROWTH setting to grow the file until it reaches the MAXSIZE or fills the drive.

This file size is the size of the file on disk and will initially be empty until you start putting data in the database.